# Erro 404 depois de configurar SSL no Apache

Tags: apache, ssl, https

Tenho um VPS rodando CentOS 7 e um servidor Apache, e tenho nele um site, em perfeito funcionamento dentro da pasta /var/www/html/meusite. Mas isso usando HTTP. Decidi então gerar um SSL para rodar o site em HTTPS. A partir de então, o site roda usando HTTPS, mas só a página inicial. O restante das páginas não carrega, me dá um erro 404 (Exemplo: "The requested URL /admin was not found on this server").

Assim está meu .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Meu VirtualHost em httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName www.meusite.com.br

ServerAdmin root@www.meusite.com.br
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/meusite/public

<Directory /var/www/html/meusite/public>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Estou quebrando a cabeça para achar o erro mas não faço ideia do que pode ser. Alguém tem alguma ideia? Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

consegui responder meu problema, então vou deixar aqui a solução, para se alguém tiver o mesmo problema. Eu estou usando o framework Laravel, e parece que no caso de quando você usa esse framework, é bom adicionar o seguinte bloco de código no arquivo ssl.conf:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/seuprojeto/public>
   AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Fiz isso e passou a funcionar certinho. O site todo roda, sem erro 404.

Comment: Favor marcar esta resposta como a correta